# Как через jQuery добавить в input текст по умолчанию?

Tags: jquery, html

Всем привет!

Есть текстовое поле, пусть будет оно логин, оно генерируется модулем через какую-то систему. Исходник найти так и не удалось - как генерируется, - но имеется его `id=#mb6b22feu_input_username`. Хочу сделать, чтобы при фокусе на данный input у меня убиралась надпись "Логин" на пустое значение. Как сделать, я уже понял

```
if (this.value == 'Логин'){
    this.value = '';
}
```

Но проблема в том, что нету текста по умолчанию, надо чтобы по умолчанию стоял текст Логин. Нужно обязательно это сделать как-то посредством jQuery, так как исходник генерирования этой формы я найти не смог! Помогите люди? Ниже приведен полный jquery код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mb6b22feu_input_username').focus(function () {
        if (this.value == 'Логин') {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("mb6b22feu_input_username").val("Логин");
    $('#mb6b22feu_input_username').focus(function () {
        if (this.value == 'Логин') {
            this.value = '';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Я считаю, что нельзя делать вот такие надписи именно в инпуте. Инпут должен оставаться пустым, а надпись в прозрачном слое над инпутом быть, которые пропускает фокус через себя.

Answer (score 1):

Надпись при фокусе можно сделать так

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT `login` FROM `users`");
 $r = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $login= $r['login'];

<input onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" value="$login" />
```

Изначально идет выборка данных из БД.

Потом присваиваем полю `login` переменную $login

Ну и вставляем эту переменную в строку.

ВНИМАНИЕ: таким образом будет происходить выборка всех логинов из БД из строки `login`,

для этого нужно писать условие.

Comment: Вы вопрос внимательно прочитали? ТС не может найти исходник в котором генерируется форма и поэтому использует jquery для задания дефолтного значение. Выборка из БД и вставка в поле выбранного логина не менее обсурден. После авторизации, эти поля скрывают, например, чтобы разместить ссылку/кнопку Выйти.

Answer (score 1):

Ребят, это называется `placeholder`, поддерживается свежими браузерами, а для остальных есть `placeholder.js`.

Comment: Совершенно верно. Можно просто в тэге прописать
    
    <input placeholder="логин" />

Ну а к странице прикрутить библиотеку для определения HTML5
www.modernizr.com

Comment: Не забываем, эта надпись будет исчезать при постановки курсора в input

Comment: Не будет. placeholder исчезает только, когда начинаем что то писать, и это правильно

Answer (score 0):

Наткнулся только что на отличный [плагин](http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/) для этих целей и сразу поспешил сюда сообщить )

Comment: Есть у всего этого один недостаток - Если я хочу ввести текст совпадающий с текстом который я хочу видеть подсказкой, значение инпута обнуляется :-( Но небольшой доработкой это можно решить :-)